# How is this series diverging given this approxiamation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I am given that a series follows the following formula:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/\sqrt{(n^2+n)} %$$

I approxiamate it with the following integral:
$$\int_1^∞ 1/x \, dx = ln(∞)-ln(1)$$
Which simplifies to infinity.

The answer says this is correct, but my question is, since $$1/\sqrt{(n^2+n)}<1/x$$
how does the integral prove anything? The fact 1/x diverges has no bearing on $$1/\sqrt{(n^2+n)}$$ since 1/x lies above it. Where is my reasoning wrong?

Comment: $1/\sqrt {n^{2}+n} >\frac  1{2n}$.

Comment: But the key says to compare with the sum of 1/n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be shown that for a continuous function $f:\mathbb{[1,\infty)}\rightarrow[0,\infty)$, the convergence of $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty f(n)$$ is equivalent to the convergence of $$\int\limits_1^\infty f(x) d x.$$

So to assess whether or not your series converges, you set $f(n) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}$ and look at the following integral:
$$\int\limits_1^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+x}} dx,$$

Since for all $x\geq 1$ we have $\frac{1}{2x^2} \leq \frac{1}{x^2+x}$, we can use the smaller function to get a bound from below for the integral in question:

$$ \int\limits_1^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+x}} dx \geq  \int\limits_1^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2x^2}} dx =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int\limits_1^\infty \frac{1}{x} dx = \infty$$